# Android cluster and marker clicks

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

I'm using the android clustering utility on a map and succesffuly implemented an onclick listener with mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener() for all the markers handled by the clustering library.

Because I also want some markers to always be unclustered, I also add some markers without using the mClusterManager but directly using the map's mMap.addMarker(), this way I'm sure that they are never clustered on the map.

My problem is that I cannot intercept clicks on those markers (the always unclustered ones) because I already used mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager) to handle the clicked clusters' markers.

Is there a way to listen to the clicked clustered markers AND the clicked markers not handled by the clustering library ?

Or is there a way to specify the cluster manager to never cluster some markers ? In this case I won't have to handle those different click listener since all markers would be shown using the clustering utility.

Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a new `MarkerManager` that you pass into the `ClusterManager` constructor. Then make a new Marker collection using `MarkerManager#newCollection` and add your normal Markers to the map using the `MarkerManager.Collection#addMarker` method.

Then, instead of calling `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)`, call `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mMarkerManager)`, and it will handle forwarding your `Marker` click events to the proper listeners. You'll also need to set up your onMarkerClick listener for normal Markers with the `MarkerManager.Collection#setOnMarkerClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener markerClickListener)` function.

I recommend looking over the source of the [MarkerManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/MarkerManager.java) and [ClusterManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java) classes to get a better idea of how the classes interact.

Comment: Perfect it's working, thx. Reading the MarkerManager link you gave really helped me, it's a good recommandation.

Comment: @NasaGeek After adding markers with `MarkerManager`, cluster is not working! Can you please provide any snippet?

Answer (score 8):

One more way to receive the click event for `Marker` is using `OnClusterItemClickListener` interface.

Call `mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);` and make your class implement `OnClusterItemClickListener`

Then inside the `onClusterItemClick` method, you will get the ClusterItem which is the marker that was clicked,

```
@Override
public boolean onClusterItemClick(ClusterItem clusterItem) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude " + clusterItem.getPosition().latitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is simpler.

Comment: But it doesn't have further attributes if you have a class that extended from `ClusterItem`. For example `Icon`, `Id`, ... .

Comment: @Mr.Hyde maybe you can trick the system, if you have a database the Lat and Lng won't change and you can reverse the data. I'd implement that in my project. Thanks @Atul!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde The item that is passed into onClusterItemClick should still retain it's original type, so you could be able to cast it to the correct object to retain the fields. i.e. MyObject mine = (MyObject) clusterItem;

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see my code. The example is complete with all you need.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MarkerClusterItem> {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        this.googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);


        setUpClusterManager();

        ...
    }

    private void setUpClusterManager(){
        // cluster
        clusterManager = new ClusterManager<MarkerClusterItem>(getActivity(), this.googleMap);
        clusterManager.setAnimation(false);
        MarkerClusterRenderer clusterRenderer = new MarkerClusterRenderer(getActivity(), googleMap, clusterManager);
        clusterManager.setRenderer(clusterRenderer);
        // marker clic
        clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MarkerClusterItem> cluster) {
    if (cluster == null) return false;
        // do your stuff here 
        return true;
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple solution

Just got the same problem. The solution is simple: call ClusterManager listeners from your own event listeners. Look at the concept:

```
private OnMapReadyCallback listenerMapReady = (googleMap) ->
{
    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(() -> {
        mClusterManager.onCameraIdle(); //call cluster manager listener
        //....your code for setOnCameraIdleListener event
    });

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
        if (marker != null && ... check if marker is NOT from cluster manager ....) {
            //......your code for unclustered markers, added directly to the map
            return false;
        }
        else
            return mClusterManager != null && mClusterManager.onMarkerClick(marker); // let cluster manager do his job
    });
}
```

To ensure that cluster manager internals will not intercept onMarkerClick listener, lets reset listener every time after cluster manager did his stuff. I've put it right into OnCameraIdle event:

```
public class FragmentRoutes extends Fragment {

private MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_routes, container, false);

    mMapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.ac_main_map); // map rendering holder
    if (mMapView != null)
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //....... other onCreate mess
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(listenerMapReady);
    }
}


// on marker click listener for the map
private GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener listenerMarkerClick = marker -> {
    //markers which tag is TransportItem were added directly to map, I will take care of them
    if (marker != null && marker.getTag() instanceof TransportItem) {
        //......do my tasks for clicked transport marker
        return false;
    }
    else {
       // other markers are cluster manager markers, process as usual
       return mClusterManager != null && mClusterManager.onMarkerClick(marker);
    }
}

// listener for map ready event
private OnMapReadyCallback listenerMapReady = (googleMap) ->
{
    if (getContext() == null)
        return;

    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(() -> {
        mClusterManager.onCameraIdle();

        //....your code for setOnCameraIdleListener event

        // now reset marker click listener
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(listenerMarkerClick); //reset marker click listener
    });
}


}
```

Thats all! Happy androiding :)