# Cluster Marker Click Event Android

Tags: cluster-computing, marker

I am using Google Maps Marker Clustering available in the `utils library`. On clicking a Cluster, the below `onClusterClick` method is not called. Is there a `Cluster click event`?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster)
    {        
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you need add this line before:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(yourClusterManager);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way that how can achieve your requirement i.e. to click on cluster or cluster item.

```
mapSupportFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap; //(Here mMap is my GoogleMap object declared & was initialized).

        // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<AppClusterItem>(MFragmentActivity.this, mMap);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyCustomRender(MFragmentActivity.this, mMap, mClusterManager)); 
        // Here which I used is my custom rendering class

        // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster manager.
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<AppClusterItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<AppClusterItem> cluster) {

                Log.e("I clicked @ ", "Cluster which consumes whole list of ClusterItems");
                return false;
            }
        });

        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<AppClusterItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterItemClick(AppClusterItem item) {
                Log.e("I clicked @ ", "Cluster Item");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This solution will then not let you to use **GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener** method, then so for it, [you can read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892325/1164529).

Answer (score 1):

maby its too late but if there any one want to know :
just set OnClusterItemClcikListener on your CkusterManger :

```
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
```

then make you class implement ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener

```
activity a implements ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener ....
```

then finaly call

```
 @Override
public boolean onClusterItemClick(ClusterItem clusterItem) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clciked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```