# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException without any reason

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

hey in my map activity when user clicks on marker application crashes and I'm getting this in logcat which is not caused by a class from my application and I can't find out why I'm getting that

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc, PID: 24320 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
         at android.util.PathParser$PathDataNode.addCommand(PathParser.java:380)
         at android.util.PathParser$PathDataNode.nodesToPath(PathParser.java:260)
         at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPath.toPath(VectorDrawable.java:1265)
         at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.drawPath(VectorDrawable.java:950)
         at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.drawGroupTree(VectorDrawable.java:931)
         at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPathRenderer.draw(VectorDrawable.java:938)
         at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.updateCachedBitmap(VectorDrawable.java:705)
         at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw(VectorDrawable.java:280)
         at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1148)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15171)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14096)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15174)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14096)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14091)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15174)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14096)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1195)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14091)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14091)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14091)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14091)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14091)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14895)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3407)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3201)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15174)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2695)
         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14096)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14119)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(Thr
```

and this is my `onMarkerClick`

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    mClusterManager.onMarkerClick(marker);
    return true;
}
```

What is this saying? And how can I fix it?

Comment: As mentioned in the second line of the log, `length=3; index=3`, you have an array with 3 items (With indices 0, 1, 2) and you are calling an item at index = 3, which doesn't exist.

Comment: but you can see exception cause from `PathParser`,`VectorDrawable`,`ImageView` and not from my application. you can see `onMarkerClick` in my post @MohanadMohie

Comment: It is not from your application, but I believe somehow you haven't' notified `mClusterManager` of the latest update in markers on the map, so it is mis-informed about the current count of the Markers. I haven't used `ClusterManager` before so I can't be of help on that topic. Perhaps [this could be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892113/android-cluster-and-marker-clicks).

Comment: Please put the SVG file that used in your map.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem was that one of your vector xml contained a [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).
Make sure that your xml vector drawables don't contain **e-** value.

UPDATE:
Your xml vector file is some thing like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:viewportHeight="32"
    android:viewportWidth="32">
    <path
        android:pathData="m 1.05e-4,2.75448" />
</vector>
```

The `android:pathData` has bad value. **e-** is invalid character and that throw exception.

Comment: Thanks dude but how did you know that? there is nothing meaningful in log

Comment: I just google this: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException android.util.PathParser$PathDataNode.addCommand` and find following link: https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid/issues/79