# MarkerOnClickListener with clusters GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an application which uses the Google Maps Api, and I want to start using Google's clustering api so multiple markers could be joined as one. According to this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering
I should add the `ClusterManager` as the `OnMarkerClickListener` like this: `getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);`

1) How do I separate the actions done on a regular unclustered marker on the map which could be far from the clustered marker, and a clustered marker?

2) What is the difference between OnClusterItemClickListener and OnClusterClickListener? I'm not sure how could an item of a cluster be clicked if they are clustered into a single marker?

Comment: thank you for accepting my answer mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from the document - [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering):

> [**ClusterItem**](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterItem.java)
>
> - represents a marker on the map.
>
> [**ClusterManager**](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java)
>
> - Groups many items on a map based on zoom level.

Based on this description

[**OnClusterItemClickListener**](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener.html)

- Called when an individual ClusterItem is clicked.

[**OnClusterClickListener**](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener.html)

- Called when a Cluster is clicked.

As a recommendation from this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892325/5995040), try looking over the source of the [MarkerManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/MarkerManager.java) and [ClusterManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java) classes to get a better idea of how the classes interact. This should cover how you interact with the clustered and unclustered markers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As cluster manager listener set to `map.setOnMarkerClickListener(yourclusermanager)`.

Now suppose separate every marker into single that will handle it by `onClusterClick`
But cluster have more than maker this click handle will notify in `onClusterItemClick`

Go through this [reference](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) link as i read it's documentation.