# How to take separate click event for Android cluster and normal marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have used clustering in my application, and i also wants some of marker unclustered (like it should not be member of clustering). Now i want marker click for both separately. As i have different action for both different markers. I have referred this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892113/android-cluster-and-marker-clicks) and i followed their steps.

I have took two different cluster manager

1.) NORMAL MARKER :

```
MarkerManager customNewMarkerManager = new MarkerManager(googleMap);
customNewMarkerManager.newCollection("DEMO").addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudemy, longitudemy)).icon(icon));
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(customNewMarkerManager);

customNewMarkerManager.getCollection("DEM").setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
// other logic here
return false;
}
});
```

2.) CLUSTERING MARKER

```
ClusterManager mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<ModelLocation>(getActivity(), googleMap);
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new PersonRenderer());
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
for (int i = 0; i < markerArrayList.size(); i++) {
mClusterManager.addItem(markerArrayList.get(i));
}
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

Now, what is happening that i can not get any of the click event.
Not this one `customNewMarkerManager.getCollection("DEM").setOnMarkerClickListener` And not event clustering click events

```
onClusterClick, onClusterInfoWindowClick, onClusterItemClick, onClusterItemInfoWindowClick
```

Can anyone have done this type of functionality or do anyone have any better idea to do this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve, but try this:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            clusterManager1.onMarkerClick(marker);
            clusterManager2.onMarkerClick(marker);
        }
    });
```